# CodePlex URL migration/maintenance

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, broken-link

Before Microsoft acquired [GitHub](https://github.com/), they hosted code on a website named [CodePlex](https://www.codeplex.com/) and it was a popular platform for .NET projects. As you can see when you visit the CodePlex page, Microsoft put the website into archive mode and is planning to shut down this service entirely on 2021-07-01 because GitHub is their preferred platform to host code.

As a result, tons and tons of old C#/WPF/.NET related questions and answers will contain dead links pointing to archived CodePlex projects that may or may not have been migrated elsewhere. Popular CodePlex repositories are [MVVM Light](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvvmlight) and [Silverlight](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=silverlight) for WPF, but there's also [Sandcastle](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sandcastle) for automatically generating .NET code documentation.

As you can see, some CodePlex projects show a prompt saying the project migrated, while others don't. I was wondering if anyone's been cleaning up URLs pointing to CodePlex or perhaps updating them with the information available on the archived project website. If not, would this not be a pretty important maintenance operation?

On the one hand, you could say that even the "newest" CodePlex projects are already four years old, and can/should be considered outdated, but one the other hand there's still projects from back in those days that are actively being maintained today elsewhere.

What will Stack Overflow do?

Comment: [Yikes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Acodeplex.com&searchOn=3)

Comment: People are still using Silverlight?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that Microsoft wouldn't keep the domain active indefinitely with redirects to GitHub or wherever the project might live on. In its 4 years of being in archive mode I am surprised they didn't give maintainers a the ability to declare a redirect URL which would be used when someone visits the project page.

Comment: I think we deal with this as we deal with any broken links; if you know of the other location, edit the post and relink, if you don't, link to the waybackmachine.org's last cached copy if present, otherwise, remove the link and if the post makes no sense any more, flag/vote to close/delete.

Comment: Also, @Zoe it's worse; all links to Codeplex redirect to the new archive page now... very stupid of Microsoft to actively break all links, but that's kind of their track record.

Comment: Has all the content from codeplex been migrated to GitHub? I mean: Is it guaranteed that a codeplex page exists now on GitHub?

Comment: @BDL No, AFAIK it is a manual process that repo owners would need to undertake themselves.

Comment: So this means we would have to check all those 52k posts "by hand" to see where to new page resides. Sounds like a ton of work :(

Comment: @BDL I think it should be feasible to grab all those links, convert them into `https://archive.codeplex.com/` format and then crawl those URLs for notification boxes? However, the editing of the URLs within the questions and answers will likely be a manual process unless there's a way to automate that as well.

Comment: Codeplex is not Jon Skeet but ... maybe ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237110

Comment: Why do we need to do anything? Stack Overflow is not a link aggregation tool. Links should not be used as the primary method of communicating information in a post. As I said, if we come across them, we can edit them, by why hunt them out? Because doing a mess of edits will bring all of those ancient questions to the front page. Do we need that? I think not.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I suppose it does, but it's still not clear to me what the consensus is on SO with the many valid answers on that meta question.

Comment: @JansthcirlU The consensus is, and always has been, that "Posts must be 100% self-sustaining." This means that all content should strive to be as complete as possible and only use links as an enhancement instead of relying on the link's content as an answer. This means that I should be able to systematically remove all links (non i.stack.imgur.com) from the Stack Exchange network and the content should not be affected. The fact that users do not abide by this rule is a separate issue.

Comment: This is one of the reasons to CodePlex and GitHub repositories are a problem, and should be avoided whenever possible, linking to (current) documentation for Microsoft is bad enough since they have changed their documentation article three times in the last decade (most of the time resulting in dead links when they do).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus they do not even keep links to their blog posts/help pages. why should even develop such a thing, to show their love of developers?

Comment: @ErdoganKurtur Loving their developers is the most ridiculous thing I've ever heard. If this was Silicone Valley you would have police at your door by now 

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I was referring to Balmer's `Developers, developers, developers` thing. We can't reliably link to the pages of even one of the biggest software companies in the world, and they develop their own browser for god's sake. This is why I donate money to archive.org